# VPN with AppHarbor

Tags: appharbor

I want to migrate my app from Rackspace to AppHarbor, but my app depends on a database that is only accessible via VPN. Can I set up a vpn connection between our app at AppHarbor and a secured internal database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit to your database server to the set of [IP addresses used by AppHarbor application servers](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/application-server-ips-ec2-configuration).

Comment: But if the database is only accessible via our VPN internal network, is that not possible to set up with an AppHarbor app?